# Use one Story Map for planning two different solutions of one process

Tags: agile, user-stories, roadmaps

Currently I am creating a story map for a product. We've defined the future process which should be represented in our new product. For the first step the user will get a classical windows application, but later on there should also be a mobile app.

I was wondering whether it makes sense to draw the functionalities of both (classical application and mobile app) in one map or work with two seperate maps.

[image: Example Story Map]

I think it will be fine to have both in one map, as both are solving the same problems / supporting the process. But as I am quite new to story mapping I would appreciate hearing some experiences / opinions from your side.

Thanks a lot!

Alex

Comment: Are the windows application and the mobile app two different products, or are they two interfaces to one product? Is it conceivable that, once the initial versions of both the windows application and the app are created, that new features might be developed for both of them at the same time?

Comment: Basically both are the interface to one product, but it seems like the app might have the one or other additional feature/goody on it, which the windows application might not have. For instance use the camera of the phone to scan a ticket, qr-code or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found story maps are a useful way to help prioritise a team's work. The map allows you to categorise what is in each release and so order your product backlog.

As such, I would suggest that combining both solutions on one map might be the better approach.

If you do two separate maps then you will have to figure out how to prioritise across them. For example:

> Release 1 from Map 1 followed by Release 1 from Map 2

You can make this approach work, but I would worry that it gets confusing if you want to pick up the odd story from one solution or the other:

> Release 1 from Map 1 followed by Release 1 from Map 2 followed by Story X from Map 1

Comment: Agree to this argumentation, my problems will start, as soon as the app is getting additional features (e.g. QR-code scanning) which will not be supported by the win app.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of Agile is to do barely sufficient documentation so that you can get going and learn more. For your immediate purposes, you need the process flow/functionality for the classical windows app so draw this first. If you think there may be specifics that are different for the mobile flow, you can add this as you find them later on, or even add them as specifics now, but at a very high level (these are in the future, so the likelihood of changes to the details of these is higher, so keep detail to the minimum required at this stage for decision making/any other immediate purposes that you need them for).

Comment: as soon as the stories for the mobile app get more detailed, you suggest to switch to a second map?